# adding New Payment processor not working on multisite environment

Tags: payment-processor, forms, validation

Drupal 9, CiviCRM 5.39.2, Domain Module

We have a multisite setup using a domain module. Each site has their own payment processor.

While adding the new payment processor, the form is not working. it never reaches the `postProcess` function and `formRule` function.

It just ignores default validation like required field name.

We had the same issue on Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 5.27.7.

There is no customisation on the `CRM_Admin_Form_PaymentProcessor` form.

Using `org.civicrm.multisite` : 2.8.0

[image]

Comment: "We had the same issue on Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 5.27.7" - were you not able to resolve it back then?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion We did not try to fix the issue in 5.27.7 as customers wanted to move to the latest version.